# Two rows are missing when using JoinRowSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I will be using [JoinRowSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/JoinRowSet.html) to join two tables (they are on different DB servers).
I was able to get it work. But, I found a serious problem.
I have two missing rows from my joines resultSet. To prove this, I joined the same query and two rows were still missing (thought i had to get back a resultset with the same row count as each joined sets).

Here is my code:

```
@Stateless
public class TestEJB {

    public void getRektCrossJoin() throws Exception {
        Connection firstDB = null;
        Connection secondDB = null;

        try {
            Context ic = new InitialContext();
            try {
                firstDB = ((DataSource) ic.lookup("java:app/env/jdbc/firstDB")).getConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                firstDB = ((DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/firstDB")).getConnection();
            }

            try {
                secondDB = ((DataSource) ic.lookup("java:app/env/jdbc/secondDB")).getConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                secondDB = ((DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/secondDB")).getConnection();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        String sqlAfa = "SELECT * FROM afa order by percent;";

        try (PreparedStatement stmtS = firstDB.prepareStatement(sqlAfa);PreparedStatement stmtJ = secondDB.prepareStatement(sqlAfa)) {

            RowSetFactory rowSetFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            try (ResultSet rsS = stmtS.executeQuery(); 
                    ResultSet rsJ = stmtJ.executeQuery(); 
                    JoinRowSet joinRowSet = rowSetFactory.createJoinRowSet()) {

                System.out.println("\n >>> First DB <<< ");
                int columnCountS = rsS.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                for(int i = 1; i<= columnCountS; i++) {
                    System.out.print(rsS.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();

                while (rsS.next()) {
                    for(int i=1; i<= columnCountS; i++) {
                        System.out.print(rsS.getString(i) + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }


                System.out.println("\n >>> Second DB <<< ");
                int columnCountJ = rsJ.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                for(int i = 1; i<= columnCountJ; i++) {
                    System.out.print(rsJ.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
                while (rsJ.next()) {
                    for(int i=1; i<= columnCountJ; i++) {
                        System.out.print(rsJ.getString(i) + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                rsS.beforeFirst();
                rsJ.beforeFirst();

                CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = rowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();
                CachedRowSet cachedRowSet2 = rowSetFactory.createCachedRowSet();

                cachedRowSet.populate(rsS);
                joinRowSet.addRowSet(cachedRowSet,2); //second field is unique

                cachedRowSet2.populate(rsJ);
                joinRowSet.addRowSet(cachedRowSet2,2); //second field is unique

                joinRowSet.first();
                if (!joinRowSet.next() ) {
                    System.err.println("No data");
                } else {
                    int columnCount = joinRowSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                    for(int i = 1; i<= columnCount; i++) {
                        System.out.print(joinRowSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i) + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    while(joinRowSet.next()) {

                        for(int i=1; i<= columnCount; i++) {
                            System.out.print(joinRowSet.getString(i) + "\t");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }

                cachedRowSet.close();
                cachedRowSet2.close();
            }
        }

        firstDB.close();
        secondDB.close();
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
INFO [stdout] Southpark DB megvan
INFO [stdout] Jerry DB megvan
INFO [stdout] 
INFO [stdout]  >>> First DB <<< 
INFO [stdout] category  percent from_date   to_date 
INFO [stdout] 0 0   1900-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 5   2018-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 18  2017-01-01  2017-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 20  1900-01-01  2009-06-30  
INFO [stdout] 1 25  2009-07-01  2011-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 27  2012-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 
INFO [stdout]  >>> Second DB <<< 
INFO [stdout] category  percent from_date   to_date 
INFO [stdout] 0 0   1900-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 5   2018-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 18  2017-01-01  2017-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 20  1900-01-01  2009-06-30  
INFO [stdout] 1 25  2009-07-01  2011-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 27  2012-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 
INFO [stdout]  >>> JoinRowSet <<< 
INFO [stdout] category  percent from_date   to_date category    from_date   to_date 
INFO [stdout] 1 20.0    1900-01-01  2009-06-30  1   1900-01-01  2009-06-30  
INFO [stdout] 2 18.0    2017-01-01  2017-12-31  2   2017-01-01  2017-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 5.0 2018-01-01  2030-12-31  2   2018-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 0 0.0 1900-01-01  2030-12-31  0   1900-01-01  2030-12-31
```

What could have happened?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I duplicated the afa select:

```
String sqlAfa = "SELECT * FROM afa order by percent DESC;";
String sqlAfa2 = "SELECT * FROM afa order by percent ASC;";
```

After this I modified the outter try-with-resources block:

```
PreparedStatement stmtJ = secondDB.prepareStatement(sqlAfa2)
```

And here is the output:

```
INFO [stdout]  >>> First DB  <<< 
INFO [stdout] category  percent from_date   to_date 
INFO [stdout] 1 27  2012-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 25  2009-07-01  2011-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 20  1900-01-01  2009-06-30  
INFO [stdout] 2 18  2017-01-01  2017-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 5   2018-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 0 0   1900-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 
INFO [stdout]  >>> Second DB <<< 
INFO [stdout] category  percent from_date   to_date 
INFO [stdout] 0 0   1900-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 5   2018-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 2 18  2017-01-01  2017-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 20  1900-01-01  2009-06-30  
INFO [stdout] 1 25  2009-07-01  2011-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 27  2012-01-01  2030-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 
INFO [stdout]  >>> JoinRowSet <<< 
INFO [stdout] category  percent from_date   to_date category    from_date   to_date 
INFO [stdout] 2 18.0    2017-01-01  2017-12-31  2   2017-01-01  2017-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 20.0    1900-01-01  2009-06-30  1   1900-01-01  2009-06-30  
INFO [stdout] 1 25.0    2009-07-01  2011-12-31  1   2009-07-01  2011-12-31  
INFO [stdout] 1 27.0    2012-01-01  2030-12-31  1   2012-01-01  2030-12-31
```

Now the missing rows changed as well.

Comment: *two rows were still missing* which one ?

Comment: Hi! From the last 4 rows you can see that those rows missing who's percent field is 25 or 27.

Comment: Are you sure they both have the keys that you're joining on? You're getting an inner join, maybe you wanted a full outer join.

Comment: Hi! No, inner join is perfect for me. In this example the percent field isn't a PK, but it's unique. I tried to join to tables with their correct PKs, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have noticed, you are missing two rows every time. So, first you move the cursor to first row

```
joinRowSet.first();
```

Then, before you start your actual loop, you have already called `next` twice and haven't printed

```
if (!joinRowSet.next() ) {
           ...
           ...
     while(joinRowSet.next()) {
```

`joinRowSet.next()` *will moves the cursor froward one row from its current position*. So, by the time, you actually started printing your row, you have already reach third row.

Comment: Good call! My eyes went over this a million times, but... (there must be a but :D)
That couns as one next() call, not two.
Now I just iterate with while(joinRowSet.next()) and I only missing one row.
In the result one of the missing rows appeared (now this is the top result):
"2 5.0 2018-01-01 2030-12-31 2 2018-01-01 2030-12-31"

So one row's missing, the one that's percent is 0.

Comment: Now i just saw (from phone) that i call first() and not beforeFirst() on joinRowSet. Thats the last missing row... I'll correct and try in first thing in the morning. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Works wonderfully! Thanks for the help, have a nice day/weekend :)